# Dynamic Vertical Alignment

Tags: jquery, html, css

Check out the page: http://www.blueclick.ca/projects/0755/html/

Question is - why is it not actually vertical aligned?

The vertical align attribute on the table cell is working, but it seems to be aligning the top of my content to the middle and not the middle of my content to the middle.

If you click the contact button on the far left you will see the ultimate goal - that the content will be initially closed and centered, and when the content is toggle slid out, the footer and header will expand away from each other and not just downwards.

Anybody have any insight to offer?

Thanks as always

Comment: What the out come you are looking for where do you want the content to end up??

Comment: @1ftw1 The outcome I'm going for is for 50% of the content (including the header) to be over the centre of the page and 50% to be below. Just to vertically center it. I can't do this with absolute positioning because when I toggle the content it just slides down and then > 50% of the content is in the bottom of the screen - I need a solution that will allow the header and footer, which are wrapped around the display:none content holding div, to expand both upwards and downward so that the entire thing remains centered when the content is toggleSlide()'d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: I had included the content div inside the header div by mistake - since the header had a set height much smaller than the content, it was centering only the header but not the content (based on a container with a height equal to only one object inside it - the header). I took it out, and it re-sizes as imagined.

Answer (score 1):

It **is** vertically aligned perfectly as far as I and Google Chromes inspect element can tell me.  If you want to test to make sure, do something like this...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var mid = $(window).height() / 2;
        var myDivMid = $("#navigation_holder").position().top - ($("#navigation_holder").height() / 2)

        alert(mid);
        alert(myDivMid);
    });
</script>
```

Assuming I didn't mess up, that should tell you the middle value of the window and the middle value of your div.